# Cannot add a COM reference to a Blazor WebAssembly project

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to add a COM reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` to a `Blazor WebAssembly` project, but it is giving me this error:

> "The assembly path  obj\Debug\net5.0\Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll is invalid. Assembly paths must be rooted."

Same issue if I need to add it as a package.

How can I fix this problem?

When I add the project it will be like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel">
        <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
        <VersionMinor>7</VersionMinor>
        <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
        <Guid>00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
        <Lcid>0</Lcid>
        <Isolated>false</Isolated>        
        <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
        <Private>true</Private>
    </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: _How_ did you add it?   But it's unlikely to work on WebAssembly.

Comment: WebAssembly isn't going to be able to call the Microsoft Office APIs on the local machine, so this isn't going to work.

Comment: @HenkHolterman from the project reference, I edited the question to show how it will look.

Comment: @MartinCostello is there anyway to write on excel from blazor?

Comment: You might be able to do it with a JS library, or using server-side code.

Comment: There are multiple Excel libs that will work with Blazor Wasm.

Comment: @sam Unless you were calling web service APIs for Office 365, I don't think it's going to work due to the browser security boundary. The web browser isn't going to be able to use the Excel APIs on the user's local machine.